# Scaling a variable by fixed scale

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I'm not sure how this mathematical problem is called so I'm going to put it forward in layman terms.

Let variable X be 100 and scale variable is 1.0:

X = 100

scale = 1.0

If we change scale to 1.25 the X is computed:

scale = 1.25

X = X * scale

Giving us result of 125

Problem is when we change scale back to 1.0, I want the original value back:

scale = 1.0

X = some formula to scale X back to 100

It seems original information is lost.

Possible values for the scale variable are 1.0, 1.25, 1.5 and 1.75

by changing scale by those possible values I need to be able to compute X for given scale always yielding the same result.

scale may jump from 1.25 to 1.75 and back to 1.0 and so on and so fort, regardless of scale X should be always the same per scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a specific name for your problem. It occurs when different system of measurements are used, i.e., the metric system and the imperial system or when we need to extend the range of the current working precision as in construction of software that cannot overflow.

In any case, the solution is to use two numbers $(x,s)$ to represent a single number $z$ given by $z = x/s$. Here the scale $s$ is typically a real number that is strictly positive, i.e., $s \in(0,\infty)$. We shall say that two pairs $(x,s)$ and $(y,t)$ are equivalent if and only if $x/s=y/t$. We make the trivial, but critical observation that $(x,s)$ is equivalent to $(x/s,1)$.

How do we change scale? We have $(x,s)$, but we wish to change the scale from $s$ to $t$. We need to find $y$ such that $x/s=y/t$. It follows that $$y = (x/s)t$$ is the only choice. Example: $(100,1)$ is equivalent to $(125,1.25)$.

How do we add number that might have different scales? What is the sum of the two numbers represented by $(x_1,s_1)$ and $(x_2,s_2)$. Well, $(x_i,s_i)$  represents the number $z_i = x_i/s_i$, so we want to compute $y = x_1/s_1 + x_2/s_2$ which we represent as $(y,1)$.

How do we scale a number that is represented by $(x,s)$ by a (real) number $\alpha$? We preserve the scale $s$ and return $(\alpha x, s)$.

I expect that this will resolve your issue. If floating point overflow is a possibility, then we need to be more careful and not explicitly compute, say, $y = x/s$ unless we are sure that the operation is safe. The details can be found in the paper ["Blocked Algorithms for Robust Solution of Triangular Linear Systems"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-78024-5_7)

Comment: Your analysis is appreciated and helpful, since I'm having this problem in a computer program to scale the UI for high DPI, there is a loss to precision due to floating point operation so this link will be helpful to study further for possibilities and applicability. thank you a lot!

Comment: @metablaster You are very welcome. Please note that the use of scaling factors will not eliminate rounding errors. In the LAPACK and StarNEig libraries they are used to ensure that the computed result does not overflow. Hence it can be evaluated in the context of the user's application. As you dealing with pixels on the screen, perhaps it will be practical to use integers $x$ and limit the scaling factors $s$ to negative powers of two?

Comment: Negative power of two only let's store scaling factor itself as not decimal, however there is no way to avoid decimal result in the end which needs to be rounded. it's not an issue because original `X` can be saved for scale 1.0 prior to computation and then reused each time. I wanted to see if there is a way around that, obviously yes but with rounding errors so it's a tradeoff. thanks.